# Bootstrap Modal showing with blank edit data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I am using a modal bootstrap but my data is not loading into the bootstrap even though I am passing it trough from the controller.

My Grid pulls in data from a list for Notes Object

```
@foreach (var notes in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@notes.LastModifedDate</td>
        <td>@notes.LastModifiedBy</td>
        <td>@notes.Notes </td>
        <td>

            <p>@notes.Id</p>   <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-id="@notes.Id" onclick="EditModal(@notes.Id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NotesEditPopupPartial"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>Edit </a>

            |<p>@notes.Id</p>   <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-id="@notes.Id" onclick="deleteModal(@notes.Id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteLink"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete </a>

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I am using the following to Return the data to the popup.

```
 public ActionResult NotesEditPopupPartial(int id ) {
        var record = _context.MISNotes.Where(w => w.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();        
        return PartialView("NotesEditPopupPartial", record);
 }
```

And using the following call to load the data but the data is not in the model for me to edit the text fields are still blank.

```
<script>    
    var AddOrEditNotes = function (id) {           
        var url = "/MISOjbects/NotesEditPopupPartial?id=" + id;    
        $("#myModalBodyDiv1").load(url, function () {
            $("#MyEditUpateModal").modal("show");

        })    
    }
</script>

<script>
    function EditModal(id) {
        $("#editMode").val(id);
    }
</script>
```

My Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="NotesEditPopupPartial">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Notes Entry</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv1">

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="linkId" id="linkId" />
        @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCaseNotes", "MISObjects", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myNotesEditForm", @name = "myNotesEditForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {                
    <form id="myForm" asp-action="">

                     
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>


        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Title" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, string.Empty, new { @style = "color:red;" })


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, new { @class = "form-control", @row = 5 })
            </div>
        </div>


        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateActioned)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateActioned, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateActioned)

        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastModifiedBy)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastModifiedBy)
        <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" id="btnEditSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>


        }
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center;display:none" id="loaderDiv">
        <img src="~/Content/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif" width="150" />
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your modal with div:

```
<div id="modalWrapper">
  <div class="modal fade" id="NotesEditPopupPartial">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

and then load and show the modal:

```
$("#modalWrapper").load(url, function () {
        $("#NotesEditPopupPartial").modal("show");
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
    var AddOrEditNotes = function (id) {           
        var url = "/MISOjbects/NotesEditPopupPartial?id=" + id;    
        $("#myModalBodyDiv1").load(url, function () {
            $("#MyEditUpateModal").modal("show");

        })    
    }
</script>

<script>
    function EditModal(id) {
        $("#editMode").val(id);
    }
</script>
```

According to your code, I didn't find where you call the AddorEditNotes function to call the NotesEditPopupPartial action and display the partial, and in the EditModel method, you also didn't call the action method to show the partial, so, the popup modal is blank.

In my opinion, I suggest you put the bootstrap Modal on the main page (with note grid), because the trigger button (Edit hyperlink) is on this page. Then, in the hyperlink click event, you could use JQuery Ajax to call the action method and load the partial view and put it on the Bootstrap Modal.

Sample code as below:

Code in the Main page:

```
@model IEnumerable<NetMvcSample.Models.Note>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowNotes";
}

<h2>ShowNotes</h2> 
<script>
    function EditModal(id) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent the hyperlink default event.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/NotesEditPopupPartial", //change the url to your owns.
            data: '{id: '+ id + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                //put the partial view in the modal content.
                $('#myModalBodyDiv1').html(data);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }
        });

    }
</script>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastModifyDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastModifiedBy)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Notes)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var notes in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
           @notes.LastModifyDate
        </td>
        <td>
           @notes.LastModifiedBy
        </td>
        <td>
            @notes.Notes
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>@notes.Id</p>   <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btnEdit" data-id="@notes.Id" onclick="EditModal(@notes.Id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NotesEditPopupPartial"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>Edit </a>

            |<p>@notes.Id</p>   <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btnDelete" data-id="@notes.Id" onclick="deleteModal(@notes.Id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteLink"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete </a>

        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="NotesEditPopupPartial">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Notes Entry</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv1">


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code in the controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NotesEditPopupPartial(int id)
    {
        var record = GetNotes().Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return PartialView("NotesEditPopupPartial", record);
    } 

    public ActionResult SaveCaseNotes(Note note)
    {
        // do something
        return View();
    }
```

Code in the NotesEditPopupPartial view (NotesEditPopupPartial.cshtml):

```
@model NetMvcSample.Models.Note


@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCaseNotes", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Note</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastModifyDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastModifyDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastModifyDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastModifiedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastModifiedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastModifiedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The output like this:
[image]